# unable to receive file name from html page to php file

Tags: php, html

This is the code from html page:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label_style_detail" align="right">Attach File&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <input class="accept_text_mandatory" type="file"   size="40" maxlength="150" name="file_name_original" tabindex="1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the code from php page where I want to insert the file name in database table:

```
$file_name_original = @basename($_FILES['file_name_original']['name']);
// $FILE_NAME      = isset($_REQUEST['FILE_NAME_ORIGINAL'])?$_REQUEST['FILE_NAME_ORIGINAL']:null;
// $file_name_original = @basename($FILE_NAME,".").PHP_EOL;
```

I have tried committed lines and non committed lines, both are not working... when I try to echo the variable its not printing anything.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($_FILES['file_name_original'])` ?

Comment: 1. Show us full form 2. You are trying to debug and in same time you are suppressing errors...

Comment: Remove the `@`, this will suppress any errors you might have, not good for debugging. And do a var_dump($_FILES); and var_dump($_REQUEST); to check what is actually being posted. Also make sure you are doing using enctype multipart in your form to allow files to be posted.